# How to convert to excel file to database?

Tags: database, excel, file

I'm using visual studio and oracle.

I have a file with excel extension and I want to put in Oracle database. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you browse web before asking.look [here](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/148.how-to-import-data-from-an-excel-file-into-a-table.aspx)